# GEOMETRY: In $\triangle ABC$ points $D$ and $E$ lie on $BC$ and $AC$, respectively.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

In $\triangle ABC$ points $D$ and $E$ lie on $BC$ and $AC$, respectively. If $AD$ and $BE$ intersect at $T$ so that $\frac{AT}{DT}=3$ and $\frac{BT}{ET}=4$, what is $\frac{CD}{BD}$?

This question is from https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2004_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_20 and although I do understand the solutions I wanted to attempt one by applying menelaus to both $\triangle BCE$ and $\triangle CAD$. I almost reach the original solution but end up with a quadratic that gives me a wrong solution. Can someone kindly complete it with specifically applying menelaus to both that will give 2 equations containing the answer ratio and $\frac{CE}{EA}$.

P.S: The answer will contain BC and AC which can be simplified to known terms.

Comment: What's wrong with the linked solution 5, which uses Menelaus's theorem?

Comment: I just wanted to explore it a little so tried to apply it to 2 triangles instead of the short solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No quadratic equation arises. By Menelaus’ Theorem, we get:

$$\frac{AE}{EC}\cdot\frac{BC}{BD}\cdot \frac{DT}{AT}=1$$
$$\frac{BD}{DC}\cdot \frac{CA}{AE}\cdot \frac{TE}{BT}=1$$
By substituting values and assuming the required ratio as $p$, we get:
$$\frac{1}{p}\cdot \frac{CE+EA}{AE} = 4$$
$$\frac{1}{p} \cdot (\frac{CE}{EA}+1)=4$$
$$\frac{AE}{EC} \cdot\frac{BD+CD}{BD} = 3$$
$$\frac{AE}{EC}(1+p)=3$$
This yields,
$$\frac{1+p}{4p-1}=3$$
Hence $$1+p=12p-3$$
And $$p=\frac{4}{11}$$

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I had actually forgotten to take reciprocal in one step which had caused the error.